# How do I display the date format in custom post types?

Tags: types, wordpress

Right now it displaying like this : 1447718400
I want it to display like this 04.12.2015

```
<span class="post-date"><?php echo(types_render_field('date', array('raw' => true) )); ?></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php function `date()`

```
<span class="post-date"><?php echo date('d.m.Y',types_render_field('date', array('raw' => true))); ?></span>
```